# How to move cursor left or right by word in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, typing

I'm in Windows and the shortcut to move the cursor 1 word to the left or right is supposed to be 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

However when I do that, in Win 7 or Win 10, it instead moves my Editor window, or any window of the app I'm currently in to the left or right side of the screen :'(

The same shortcut works perfectly in OSX of course.

Cursor position:

[image: cursor on the left]

Expected cursor position when clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

[image: cursor to the right]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mispressing the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> [snaps the current window to the left/right respectively](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027324/windows-10-snap-your-windows). The shortcut for moving words in Windows and all common OSes apart from macOS has always been <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is the left-most key on the keyboard (barring <kbd>Fn</kbd> on a few keyboards).

If you come from macOS you may have the habit of pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd> to move words and <kbd>Option</kbd> lies exactly in the <kbd>Windows</kbd>/<kbd>Super</kbd> key position in other OSes

Comment: Ah thanks! But ugh that I have to use the <kbd>FN</kbd> I'm having to code in a Win 7 VM inside of my beautiful Mac :( have a mechanical keyboard with custom keycaps.

Comment: then swap the Fn and Cmd key on your mac

Comment: *"I'm having to code in a Win 7 VM inside of my Mac."*  @LeonGaban we are always glad to help, but you probably should have revealed that within the original text of your question.  It would have made all the difference in the subsequent answers.